# App Transport Security, exception domain issue

Tags: ios, info.plist, app-transport-security, nsapptransportsecurity

In an iOS app, I am having troubles with App Transport Security:

I have read many post on the net, but for some reason what I set in my Info.plist seems to be ignored. I have tried several possibilities, here is the last one:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ……..
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>mydomain.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    ……..
</dict>
</plist>
```

But whatever I set in the  Info.plist I keep getting this message:

```
2016-03-25 13:21:17.234 MyApp[3587:1285514] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any hidden .plist file in your project. You can right click on your project from project navigator, click on show in finder and see if there is any other plist file.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use :

```
`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>Allow Arbitrary Loads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>`
```

This allows **ALL** unsecured links, unless if you do not care about security of information. The way you did it should be correct, maybe use the `NSTemporaryThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` might help you!

Check this: [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

Comment: I agree with what you say. In reality it is not always so easy. For example if the purpose of your app is to allow the user to do something with a URL of her/his choice (like an internet browser for example) then you don't have much choice. Another case I had is when using http://www.startapp.com/ for banners.

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly define that you do not want to Allow Arbitrary Loads, then your exception will apply to that rule.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score -1):

i hope it will work for you.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
……..
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>Allow Arbitrary Loads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
 ……..
  </dict>
  </plist>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried and it did not work.
On top of that, this solution is not recommended because not secure.
Thanks anyway for the answer.